# Firebase admin sdk listen to realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Hi i was learning Firebase realtime database in my spring project using Firebase admin SDK. My main intension is to send the notification to users based on child(new chat) items added to the main node of firebase database. [image]

Just like in above image my database tree structure is simple and it has main node called `CHATS` under this node am creating many other `child node to create 1-to-1` chat between two users. Evey single child node will have many other child nodes with chat messages.

Using Firebase admin sdk am listening to main node ie. `CHATS`

```
  private void startListeningToChats() {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    try {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/" + appProperties.firebaseChatBucketName);
        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                System.out.println("Child Event added" + s + " " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + " " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                latch.countDown();
                System.out.println("Child Event changed" + s + " " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + " " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("Child Event removed" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                System.out.println("Child Event moved" + s + " " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("Child Event cancelled" + databaseError.getMessage());
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Now when ever any changes happens to child nodes, i.e when new new chat message is added inside child node, `onChildChanged` method is fired with datasnapshot having all the child nodes. Suppose if new chat message is added to `USER5-USER6` node then `onChildChanged` method is fired with all previous chat messages but i know this is expected behaviour. And the reason am attaching listener to main node is to know when new chat node is initiated between two users. Am afraid of firebase costing if my child node has multiple chat messages then everytime `onChildChanged` method will have datasnapshot with all chat messages.

I wanted to know if we can filter the changes the done to child node so that to have `onChildChanged` with child node with lastest added chat message.

Answer (score 0):

I went through similar problems a while ago when I tried to write a chat app in android. I'm sad to tell you that there is no effective way to only take the recent data. You can use Query to manipulate the way you fetch data from the database, it still wouldn't be that effective. Also the expense in downloading all the data every time is almost insignificant. So, I'd say you look into the Query functions for Java Admin SDK and if it isn't of any help, you can proceed with retrieving all data and filtering it yourself. There is one solution though, but it is effective as long as you avoid concurrent users using the same account. You can maintain two copies of the same message, one node will contain all messages which you can use whenever you login and you have to display all the previous chats. The messages that is currently being sent will be added to another node, this messages will be retrieved by the other user and will be added to the first node, and the same message from here can be deleted, so that only the messages that was left unopened will remain on this branch.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, but then how did you solved it?

Comment: I sorted the messages from firebase using the query object and I used a variable to store the value of the last key, whenever the onChildAdded method was invoked, I will retrieve all the messages after the key that I stored in the variable. This is possible using the startAt() method which comes under the Query object.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant to say by `but it is effective as long as you avoid concurrent users using the same account`

Comment: In case of concurrent access, the second node which is being used to temporarily store the message will be accessed by multiple sources at the same time, no assume that one of these apps is a few seconds faster than another one. The faster one will remove the message as soon as it reads it. So, the second app will not download it as it got deleted by the first one. I had this problem when I tried this method and I couldn't restrict concurrent access to the database using the same credentials.